# Was Jesus a sun god?

Tags: life-of-jesus

[image: mutual qualities of the biblical Jesus and the ancient sun god Horus]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://kingalpha.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/20131221-174253.jpg?w=723))</sub>

Hello people,

Can anyone explain to me how I can maintain my Christian faith in the light of evidence that many other saviour stories from even more ancient religions have exactly the same episodes as many from the gospels, most remarkably the three days between death and resurrection?

The claim is that Jesus,  along with the Hindu's Krishna and mythological figures like the Egyptian god Horus, Greek Dionysus and Roman Mithra are versions of Pagan sun worship.

In the Northern hemisphere,  the sun's zenith suspends its move across the horizon for three days at midwinter. The theory is that this is the origin of Christ's time in the tomb, moved to Easter perhaps to coincide with the Jewish passover.

When the sun "stops" I am told that the three stars of Orion's belt point directly at the sun.  This is said to be the origin of the three wise men.

How can the Christian articles of faith that Jesus was both a historical figure and the son of God who died for our sins stand up against this theory that he is instead the sun of God?

Comment: To address your very first sentence, there's a whole field of study dedicated to defending the reasonableness of Christianity. It's called Apologetics. Almost any challenge that's ever been thrown at Christianity is answered on dozens of Apologetic sites.

Answer (score 3):

Horus cannot equal Jesus, one reason is that Horus stands in no chance compared to Jesus on morality.

Further these claims about Horus vs Jesus are already debunked on this website, please have a read https://gotquestions.org/Jesus-myth.html

> Horus was born to Isis; there is no mention in history of her being
>   called “Mary.” Moreover, “Mary” is our Anglicized form of her real
>   name, Miryam or Miriam. “Mary” was not even used in the original
>   texts of Scripture. • Isis was not a virgin; she was the widow of
>   Osiris and conceived Horus with Osiris.  • Horus was born during month
>   of Khoiak (Oct/Nov), not December 25. Further, there is no mention in 
>   the Bible as to Christ’s actual birth date.  • There is no record of
>   three kings visiting Horus at his birth. The Bible never states the
>   actual number of magi that came to see Christ.  • Horus is not a
>   “savior” in any way; he did not die for anyone.  • There are no
>   accounts of Horus being a teacher at the age of 12.  • Horus was not
>   “baptized.” The only account of Horus that involves water is one
>   story where Horus is torn to pieces, with Isis requesting the
>   crocodile god to fish him out of the water.  • Horus did not have a
>   “ministry.”  • Horus did not have 12 disciples. According to the Horus
>   accounts, Horus had four demigods that followed him, and there are
>   some indications of 16 human followers and an unknown number of
>   blacksmiths that went into battle with him.  • There is no account of 
>   Horus being betrayed by a friend.  • Horus did not die by crucifixion.
>   There are various accounts of Horus’ death, but none of them involve
>   crucifixion.  • There is no account of Horus being buried for three
>   days.  • Horus was not resurrected. There is no account of Horus
>   coming out of the grave with the body he went in with. Some accounts
>   have Horus/Osiris being brought back to life by Isis and then
>   becoming the lord of the underworld.

[image]